# ImportError: No module named bs4 on mac with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, anaconda

I'm trying to install Beautiful Soup 4.6.0 on my mac, but I keep on getting the error message below:

[image: Image from Beautiful Soup]

I have tried to install it as easy install and pip install beautifulsoup, but still keep on getting the same error message.

The terminal description is below:

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Looks like you're not running Anaconda shell

Comment: Also, beautifulsoup 3.2.1 is being installed

Comment: Im using the Python 2.7 shell, but I have Anaconda installed. How do I use the Anaconda shell instead?

Comment: Any idea Cricket?

Comment: Well, that would depend on your PATH variable... And in the first picture, `BeautiFul` is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in terminal, type`python -m pip install beautifulsoup`
if that doesn't work, try updating pip

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then retry the first command

Comment: I tried to do the above, but still getting the same error message. 

I have added in the image from the terminal above.

Comment: try running a python console and importing bs4 again, the message said it's installed correctly